# Managing several user agents on each request using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I use the following code to insert a code in a search bar, click a button and finally extract some information:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url =  'https://www.ufficiocamerale.it/'

vat = '06655971007'

useragent = UserAgent()

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", useragent.random)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)

item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="formRicercaAzienda"]//input[@id="search_input"]')
item.send_keys(vat)

time.sleep(1)

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="formRicercaAzienda"]//p//button[@type="submit"]')
button.click()

time.sleep(5)

all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="first-group"]/li')
for item in all_items:
    if '@' in item.text:
        print(item.text.split(' ')[1])
        
driver.close()
```

Now I would like to modify the code to handle the above process several times thanks to a for loop, i.e. something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url =  'https://www.ufficiocamerale.it/'

vats = ['06655971007', '06655971007', '01010101010']

for vat in vats:
    useragent = UserAgent()
    # rest of the code
```

but it does nothing. Where am I doing wrong? Is it the definition of user agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be more specific about "it does nothing" please ?

Is code without loop is working fine ?
*when testing it on this web site, for "06655971007" as input, it won't write anything because no @ in returned string

**EDIT**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
#from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url =  'https://www.ufficiocamerale.it/'

vats = ['06655971007', '06655971007', '01010101010']

for vat in vats:
    #useragent = UserAgent()

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "useragent.random")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
    #driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(5)

    item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="formRicercaAzienda"]//input[@id="search_input"]')
    item.send_keys(vat)

    time.sleep(1)

    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@id="formRicercaAzienda"]//p//button[@type="submit"]')
    button.click()

    time.sleep(5)

    all_items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="first-group"]/li')
    found_it = False
    for item in all_items:
        if '@' in item.text:
            print(vat + " = " + item.text.split(' ')[1])
            found_it = True
    if not found_it:
        print(vat + " no email found")

driver.close()
```

With output like this :

```
01010101010 no email found
08157270961 = vince.srl@legalmail.it
06655971007 = enelenergia@pec.enel.it
```

Comment: Right now I can't even extract anything. But it worked before. Perhaps the user agent is the problem and not the loop. "it does nothing" means it extracts nothing, not even without a loop (it worked before)

Comment: maybe web site is slower now, and need longer time sleep ?

Comment: In any case, would it be correct to put the for loop at the beginning of everything? And is it correct how I use the user agent?

Comment: Yes it is. I have tested it with chrome driver, and it works ok even with current sleep value. When executing, is selenium browser shows up ?

Comment: Yes, a new Firefox window opens with each run. What changes did you make to correct the code?

Comment: Use chrome instead of Firefox + remove UserAgent usage and provide a constant for "profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "useragent.random")".

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. The only problem is that when I restart the code it no longer works (or prints only partial information). Do you have any idea what the problem might be? I'm working in Jupyter Notebook, if it matters.

Comment: not sure about Jupyter notebook, but I just re-ran sample program and now output is not same. (last value, 01010101010, doesn't provide email anymore)
It sounds like website change data for this particular id.

Comment: 01010101010 is a fake code, it is normal that it does not return anything. I had put it as an example, I should have specified it. However it seems that the button is not working ("the script" clicks it but it stays on the same page). If I try to do the same thing manually (i.e. by entering the site, entering a code and clicking the button) the same thing happens.

Comment: I've updated sample, and provide different input + sample output related. Each run works with same results.
Even for fake code, it display an output with no email, I guess it's probably some error displayed. Not Italian proof, sorry ;)

Comment: I checked the situation step by step: the button is protected by a captcha. It seems that I have to consider commercial solutions to solve this issue. Your answer helped me a lot though, thank you.